# mPDF page breaking too early in <tbody>

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a mPDF output that essentially includes a table that is page-breaking in an unfortunate place.

The table is made up of a thead section, followed by several tbody's that each have a group-header row followed by detail rows - but the page break is leaving the group-header-row "orphaned" (or is it "widowed"). The problem isn't so much that the table is being broken, it's that it's only showing one row in the group before breaking.

Initially I thought of putting in page-break-inside:avoid on the css for the tbody, but this does not work (it "works" on the table but not on the tbody).

Another option would be to break each section into their own table, but this would lead onto column width inconsistencies that I would like to avoid.

Is there a way to stop mPDF from leaving too few widows/orphans? (I want to have at least two (or three) rows of each tbody showing but it would be nice to set this as an option**).

```
<?php

include_once('MPDF56_1/mpdf.php');

class Test {
public function doTest() {

    $css=/**@lang CSS */"
    table {
        width:100%;
        border:solid 1px grey;
    }
    th, td {
        text-align:left;
        padding:4px;
    } 
    th {
       background-color:#d1dce1;
    }
    .grouphead {
        background-color:#e2e2e2;
    }
    ";


    $table="<table>";
    $table.="<thead>";
    $table.="<tr><th>Some header</th></tr>";
    $table.="</thead>";

    for($tb=1; $tb<=3; $tb++) {
        $table .= "<tbody>";
        $table.="<tr><td class='grouphead'>Group $tb Header</td></tr>";
        for ($i = 1; $i < 34; $i++) {
            $table .= "<tr><td class='detail'>Some data $tb.$i</td></tr>";
        }
        $table.="</tbody>";
    }


    $table.="</table>";
    $head="<head><style>$css</style></head>";
    $body="<body>$table</body>";

    $mpdf = new mPDF('', 'A4');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<html>$head$body</html>");
    $mpdf->Output();
}
}

$try = new Test();
echo $try->doTest();
?>
```

(I'm using PHP7 & mPDF5.6 currently but can upgrade if newer versions have this function)

** e.g. ;